# Beagleboard/Angstrom freezing serial port application

Tags: java, serial-port, freeze, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I have a java application running on Beagleboard-xM/Angstrom, but when the serial communication starts, after some time, the application freezes and I have to cancel the process (ctrl + c on terminal). I already try to do the same in C, but it also freezes.

In Java, I am using RxTx library and in another forum someone told me that the Raspberry Pi has a similar problem. Can someone suggest me something? Does anyone already found out this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Long time have been passed... If anyone found this problem, it was solved for me when I use usb cable instead of serial cable... Maybe the problem be with beagleboard hardware, as I saw comments in some forums speaking about hardware problems in raspberryPy that caused this kind of error.

I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time have been passed... If anyone found this problem, it was solved for me using usb cable instead of serial cable... Maybe the problem be with beagleboard hardware, as I saw comments in some forums speaking about hardware problems in raspberryPy that caused this kind of error. I hope it can help someone.